# SQL Server how to run update on dynamic list of table names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to update dynamic list of tables.

Here is the sample SQL query:

```
EXEC('Update' + is_c.TABLE_NAME + 'SET MemberId = UPPER(MemberId)')    
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as is_c
WHERE is_c.COLUMN_NAME = 'MemberId'
```

But I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'is_c'. Expecting GLOBAL_VAR, STRING, TEXT_LEX
>   or VARIABLE

Comment: This isn't a query.  `EXEC()` is a function.  I think you need to review how dynamic SQL works in SQL Server.

Comment: Obligatory link for dynamic SQL in MS SQL: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = (
SELECT '
    UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
    SET MemberId = UPPER(MemberId) '
    -- + ' WHERE MemberId != UPPER(MemberId)'
FROM sys.tables t
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
            AND c.name = 'MemberId'
    )
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

--PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXEC` does not work that way. Use `SELECT`, and then either execute the resulting commands manually, or loop over the result with a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'if exists(select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as is_c WHERE is_c.COLUMN_NAME = ''MemberId'' and is_c.TABLE_NAME=''?'')
                   begin
                   update ? set MEmberid = UPPER(memberid)
                   end'
```

use sp_msforeachtable procedure